# average if greater than zero vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to average a column but only if the value is greater than zero. I then want it to put the information in the next blank cell in that row.

The below code was working as a simple Average but I want it to exclude any values of zero from the above cells.

```
With Range("D2")
    .End(xlDown)(2, 1) = _
    "=AVERAGE(" & .Address & ":" & .End(xlDown).Address & ")"
End With
```

I Tried with the following code to have it as if the cell address is greater than zero. But it keeps giving me an error to debug?

```
With Range("D2")
    .End(xlDown)(2, 1) = _
    "=AVERAGEIF(" & .Address & ":" & .End(xlDown).Address & "," & Cell.Address & " > 0," & .Address & ":" & .End(xlDown).Address & ")"
End With
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks
Al

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax for the formula is wrong.

You need to create a formula like

```
=AVERAGEIF(D2:Dxx, ">0")
```

So use this

```
With Range("D2")
    .End(xlDown)(2, 1) = _
    "=AVERAGEIF(" & .Address & ":" & .End(xlDown).Address & ","">0"")"
End With
```

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly. I guess I just tried to mirror doing the formula in excel :-|