# find average of all non-zero values in an array

Tags: excel, vba

I have populated an array with five values. The values were pulled from cells elsewhere in the spreadsheet. How do I find the average of all nonzero values? 
I tried a for-next loop, but couldn't skip the zero values without another conditional statement.  I assume there is a dedicated command for it.  Thanks in advance!

```
Dim varIncome as variant
varIncome = Application.Transpose(Range("B3:B7").Value)
```

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26072295/average-if-greater-than-zero-vba

Comment: `Averageifs()?`  What have you tried

Answer (score 0):

Try this (**note:** I didn't use the *varIncome* variable as it didn't seem necessary in order to get a result):

```
Sub avgNonZeroNumbers()
'Declare:
Dim rng As Range

'Initialize:
Set rng = Sheet3.Range("B3:B7") 'Change Sheet3 to your actual sheet's code name

'   Print result to the Immediate window
    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(rng, "<>0")
End Sub
```